# hchart() Bar Graph does not display all the x axis labels in R

Tags: r, highcharts, data-visualization

I have the following data frame that has the variables city, description and n.

```
city <- c("BIG COTTONWOOD", "BOUNTIFUL", "CANYON RIM", "CANYON RIM", 
"CANYON RIM", "COPPERTON", "COTTONWOOD HEIGHTS", "DRAPER", "DRAPER", 
"EAST MILLCREEK", "FARMINGTON", "FARMINGTON", "HERRIMAN", "HERRIMAN", 
"HERRIMAN", "HERRIMAN", "HOLLADAY", "KEARNS", "KEARNS", "MAGNA", 
"MAGNA", "MAGNA", "MAGNA", "MAGNA", "MIDVALE", "MIDVALE", "MIDVALE", 
"MIDVALE", "MIDVALE", "MURRAY", "MURRAY", "MURRAY", "MURRAY", 
"MURRAY", "MURRAY", "MURRAY", "NORTH SALT LAKE", "OLYMPUS COVE", 
"OLYMPUS COVE", "PARK CITY", "RIVERTON", "SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", 
"SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", 
"SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", "SALT LAKE CITY", 
"SALT LAKE COUNTY", "SALT LAKE COUNTY", "SANDY", "SANDY", "SANDY", 
"SANDY", "SANDY", "SANDY", "SOUTH JORDAN", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", 
"SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", 
"SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH SALT LAKE", "SOUTH WEST SL COUNTY", 
"TAYLORSVILLE", "TAYLORSVILLE", "TAYLORSVILLE", "TOOELE", "UTAH COUNTY", 
"WEST JORDAN", "WEST JORDAN", "WEST JORDAN", "WEST JORDAN", "WEST MILLCREEK", 
"WEST MILLCREEK", "WEST MILLCREEK", "WEST MILLCREEK", "WEST MILLCREEK", 
"WEST MILLCREEK", "WEST MILLCREEK", "WEST VALLEY CITY", "WEST VALLEY CITY", 
"WEST VALLEY CITY", "WEST VALLEY CITY", "WEST VALLEY CITY", "WEST VALLEY CITY", 
"WEST VALLEY CITY", "WEST VALLEY CITY", "WOODS CROSS", "WOODS CROSS"
)
description <- c("PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", "LARCENY", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"PUBLIC PEACE", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", "NONREPTABL TA", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", "DAMAGED PROP", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"DAMAGED PROP", "DRUGS", "LARCENY", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "ASSAULT", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", 
"LARCENY", "PUBLIC ORDER", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"PUBLIC PEACE", "REPORTABLE TA", "ASSAULT", "DAMAGED PROP", "DRUGS", 
"ESCAPE", "LARCENY", "PUBLIC ORDER", "STOLEN VEHICLE", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"ESCAPE", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC ORDER", "ASSAULT", 
"DAMAGED PROP", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "LARCENY", "NONREPTABL TA", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "REPORTABLE TA", "STOLEN VEHICLE", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "REPORTABLE TA", "DAMAGED PROP", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", 
"NONREPTABL TA", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"ASSAULT", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "LARCENY", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", 
"REPORTABLE TA", "STOLEN VEHICLE", "PUBLIC ORDER", "ESCAPE", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "DAMAGED PROP", "PUBLIC PEACE", 
"DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "ASSAULT", 
"DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "LARCENY", "NONREPTABL TA", "PUBLIC ORDER", 
"PUBLIC PEACE", "ASSAULT", "DRUGS", "ESCAPE", "NONREPTABL TA", 
"PUBLIC ORDER", "PUBLIC PEACE", "REPORTABLE TA", "STOLEN VEHICLE", 
"DAMAGED PROP", "PUBLIC ORDER")

n <- c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 6L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4029L, 2496L, 4837L, 
3637L, 11432L, 2348L, 8008L, 3798L, 2210L, 2341L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 15L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 16L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L)

slc <- data.frame(city,description,n)
```

I am using the highcharter() package made available by J.Kunst to display the above data frame in a grouped bar chart. I ran the following commands for the same.

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
colors <- c("#487098","#484898","#34348d","#19198b","#208582","#942f59","#dd125b","#000000","#c61051","#000FFF")


slc %>%  hchart("column",x=city,y=log(n*100),group=description)%>%hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google()) %>% hc_colors(colors)
```

The grouped bar chart is being displayed properly , with a slight issue. Not all the `slc$city` variables are shown on the x -axis. This is probably due to the number of city variables available. Is there a way to reduce the text display size? (similar to `geom_text` in `ggplot2`) Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could force display of all xAxis labels by setting [xAxis.labels.step](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step) to `1`. Rotation of the labels will not be calculated very well every time, so you could set [rotation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation) to `-90` through settings.

```
slc %>%  hchart("column",x=city,y=log(n*100),group=description) %>%
    hc_add_theme(hc_theme_google()) %>%
    hc_colors(colors) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(labels = list(rotation = -90, step = 1))
```

Result:

[image]

Demo for Highcharts (without R): http://jsfiddle.net/Lv12u7cg/